# Merge vs Sort: ordering dataframe by month/year

Tags: r, sorting, datetime, merge

I need to sort a data frame chronologically according to months/years format and get monthly sum and mean.
I've tried several attempts: it's a problem of merging or of sorting, and I didn't get a clean data frame.

Here is a reproducible example.
Date is supposed to be class() format.

```
Date <- c('2008-05-12','2006-01-30', '2006-02-29', '2006-01-15', '2008-05-20','2008-09-26')
Income <- c(10, 20, 30, 20, 10, 20)
df<-data.frame(Date,Income)
```

I'd like to achieve a data.frame of this form

```
ShortDate  Sum    Mean
01-2006    40      20
02-2006    30      30
05-2008    20      10
09-2008    20      20
```

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: There are only 28 days in Feb or 2006

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we group by the `format`ted 'Date' (`%m-%Y`), and `summarise` with the `sum` and `mean` of 'Income'.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(ShortDate = format(as.Date(Date), "%m-%Y")) %>% 
   summarise(Sum = sum(Income), Mean = mean(Income)) 
#   ShortDate   Sum  Mean
#      <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1   01-2006    40    20
#2   02-2006    30    30
#3   05-2008    20    10
#4   09-2008    20    20
```

---

Or in `base R` with `aggregate`

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(Income~ShortDate,
   transform(df, ShortDate = format(as.Date(Date), "%m-%Y")),
         FUN = function(x) c(Sum = sum(x), Mean = mean(x))))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. I didn't know about library(dplyr). Is there a way to get in base R?

Comment: @MoOdEV  Updated with a `base R` option

Comment: when I try with it other datasets I don't get ordered dataframe with respect to months and years but only respect months.

Comment: @MoOdEV Please check if have the correct 'Date' format

Comment: class(Date) is factor.when I aggregare respect ShortDate I lost chronologically year ordering. I get something like "01/2009" "01/2010" "02/2009" "02/2010"

Comment: @MoOdEV  I think your format is different than the one you showed here

Comment: @akun I made a mistake in previous comment. I get "01/2009" "01/2010" "02/2009" "02/2009". How could I order it?

Comment: @MoOdEV  If you look at my code, it is `format(as.Date(Date), "%m-%Y")`, so it is `-` and `/`.  How did you get `/`

Comment: short      sum     mean
1 01-2015  1650000 825000.0
2 01-2016 42800000 750877.2
3 02-2015  3275000 818750.0

Comment: @MoOdEV I think after the `summarise` do an `arrange` i.e. `%>% ungroup() %>% arrange(as.Date(paste0(ShortDate, "-01"), "%m-%Y-%d"))`